# Adding a class to a table when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do i add a class to a table once a checkbox is selected, and then remove once is dis-selected. i've got the following script

```
   .opacity40{
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    }

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />   

<script>
    $("#tableDist").addClass("opacity40");
        $("input#mycheckbox").click(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked") {
                $("#tableDist").rmoveClass("opacity40");
            }
            else {
                $("#tableDist").addClass("opacity40");
            }
        })
</script>

      <table id="tableDist">
    </table>
```

Comment: (OT) Have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#tableDist").addClass("opacity40");
$("input#mycheckbox").change(function () {
  $("#tableDist").toggleClass("opacity40");
});
```

Adil's answer is correct, though this one is much shorter.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLjG7/2)** (**with** fancy transition effect! :D)

Answer (score 0):

There are few correctionzs and suggestions.

*Corrections*

1. Wrong spelling of `removeClass`, change `rmoveClass` to
   `removeClass`
2. You also **missed** the closing parenthesis of if statememt.

*Suggestions*

1. Add some data in table as well.
2. Also put your script in head tag or just before closing tag of body.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwvc9/)**

```
$("#tableDist").addClass("opacity40");
 $("input#mycheckbox").click(function () {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $("#tableDist").removeClass("opacity40");
   } else {
     $("#tableDist").addClass("opacity40");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Classic
$("#checkBox-id").change(function(){
    $("#tableDist").toggleClass("opacity40");
});


// First way 
if($('#checkBox-id').attr('checked'))
{
   $("#tableDist").toggleClass("opacity40");
} 

// Second way 
if($('#checkBox-id').is(':checked'))
{
   $("#tableDist").toggleClass("opacity40");
}
```

Also...

```
// Third way for jQuery 1.2
$("input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").each( 
    function() { 
       $(this).toggleClass("opacity40");
    } 
);
// Third way == UPDATE jQuery 1.3
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( 
    function() { 
       $(this).toggleClass("opacity40");
    } 
);
```